# Django: Reuse ModelForm with different Models

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a schedule with different responsibilities. I want to order the participants for a rotation, like:

1. Participant 12
2. Participant 4
3. etc...

I was going to save each responsibility order in a different `model`. Since my `ModelForm` is the same for each responsibility, is it possible to change the `model` being used when the `form` is instantiated?

```py
class ReusableModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = desired_model


# Call it like this
ReusableModelForm(data, desired_model=MyModel_1)

ReusableModelForm(data, desired_model=MyModel_2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django alreaady has such functionality: the [**`modelform_factory(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory). This function is used to create forms in a `CreateView` for example.

You can thus construct a form class with:

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory

MyModel_1Form = modelform_factory(MyModel_1, fields='__all__')
```

You can for example subclass with:

```
class MyModel_1Form(modelform_factory(MyModel_1, fields='__all__')):
    class Meta:
        labels = {
            'some_field': 'some_label',
        }
```

Then later you can thus construct a form instance with `MyModel_1Form()`. The `MyModel_1Form` inherits from [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

We can use this to construct *ad hoc* forms and for example pass data to it like:

```
def modelform_init(model, *args, fields='__all__', **kwargs):
    return modelform_factory(model, fields=fields)(*args, **kwargs)
```

We can then, if you do not want to customize, construct a `ModelForm` *instance*, with:

```
modelform_init(MyModel_1, request.POST)
```

Comment: And what if I want to customize the form? Will I have to redefine them every time?

Comment: I think what I was looking for was the `form=ModelForm`. And this will probably sound really stupid, but is the `form` an existing `Form` or `ModelForm`?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker: a `ModelForm`. Note that `MyModel_1Form` is a *`class`*, not an instance of that class.